# Ruby on Rails 3: rails_admin + puret?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, integration, translation, rails-admin

Did someone try to integrate [puret](https://github.com/jo/puret) into [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)? I can't make a language switch to edit different translations :(
Changing I18n.locale forces whole rails_admin to use specified locale.

Comment: Checkout that one: https://gist.github.com/1083368

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped. Please post comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Lets wait, may be somebody else will find some better solution. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Now I got the solution. The two can work together well. In short:

> Delete the pureted column(s) in your model

If you have the column pureted still in your model, *rails form helper* will bypass puret. That is, if a model called **Post** has a field called **contents** to be i18ned, the table **posts** *SHOULD NOT* have the column **contents**.

Actually we should use [globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) instead. With this you do not need to remove the original column. And puret doens't support nested attributes assignment. globalize3 works very well.